# no net force while moving in a unifom speed and smooth surface

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

if a body is moving with uniform speed in a particular direction on a perfectly smooth surface no net force acts on it.WHY?

Comment: If you apply a force to a body, what happens to that body?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_laws_of_motion

Comment: In fact, your question includes redundant information: if a body is moving with uniform speed in a particular direction, no net force acts on it. Whether or not the surface is smooth is irrelevant. The fact that the velocity is uniform is all you need to know to conclude that the net force is zero.

Comment: @tok3rat0r That's probably worth recording in an answer.

Comment: Hi. Would you tell, why not? Do you have a thought or an objection or you are only asking why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question states that the object is moving at **constant velocity** which already implies that there is no **net force**. This is evidenced by Newton's 3rd law of Motion, when an object experiences a net force, it will accelerate with equal magnitude and direction to the net force. (Fnet = ma)

Comment: One should add that "laws " are distillation of observations needed so that a theoretical model based on them as postulates (as axioms for physics)  can describe and predict the behavior of matter under study. The answer to "why" this law, is "because" that is the behavior which has been measured/observed and can be predicted by the law".